# How to make iPod Music app ? AVPlayer - AVAudioPlayer - MPMusicPlayController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have a songs list in document directory..
Here is a code for fetching those songs...

```
NSArray *pathSong = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectorySong = [pathSong objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *managerSong = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectorySong stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Downloads"];
NSString *folPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Folder"];
NSArray *fileListSong = [managerSong contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Folder"]error:nil];
```

After that these songs play in player like iPod music library..

I have try with `MPMusicPlayController` but its only for picking songs from music library not from document directory of the app..

Also try with AVAudioPlayer but cant get Artist,  AlbumName, Title , ArtImage property of current playing song..

here is a also code of `AVPlayer`

But its fetch data from library, And I want only from document directory..

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    NSArray *songs = query.items;

NSURL *itemURL = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

        if (!avPlayer) {
            avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:itemURL];
        } else {
            [avPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:itemURL]];
            avPlayer.rate = 0.0f;
        }
```

But not get songs from Document Directory,

Can any one explain me which player better to use ?

i am making music player as like iPod Music app..

Comment: If you want to program a music player 'like the iPod Music app' then you use MPMusicPlayerController which accesses the user's iPod library.

Comment: Dear, I already write that, I dont need to use iPod library, only songs play from document directory of the app...